# Listen and store values and emit after x seconds from the first value stored time?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

RxJS 4:

I am trying to store some values and emit them after x seconds from the first value stored time (in other words, the first value received from websocket will toggle the timer to store the incoming values and then emit after x seconds). After values are emitted, the timer will stop and no values will be emitted. Until I received a new value from websocket, the cycle begins again.

The reason is that currently in my app, it will likely to emit a value every nanosecond (the websocket data) and it's kinda affecting the performance. I am thinking to store as many values I can receive for x second, then emitting those values together to do some batch calculations all at once.

I have tried this but it seems not to work as expected.

```
         public testObs = new Observable<any>();
         public bufferStarted = false;
         private subject = new Subject<any>();

         webSocket.onmessage = ((event: any) => {
            this.subject.next(event.data);
            if(!bufferStarted) {
                bufferStarted = true;

                //start the buffer now
                const startInterval = Observable.timer();

                //emit value after 1s and close buffer
                const closingInterval = val => {
                    console.log(`Buffer is open! Emitting value after 1s`)
                    bufferStarted = false;
                    return Observable.interval(1000);
                }
                this.testObs = this.subject.bufferToggle(startInterval, closingInterval);
             }
         }
```

In component, I subscribe to `testObs.subscribe((e) => ... )`. Example: A value is sent through the websocket, and it started the timer that opens the buffer for 1 second. Within 1 second, 50 more values are received from websocket. I was expecting 51 values (array length of 51) received in the component. However I received that the observable is undefined. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bufferTime` seems to be a good choice for you.
It will group the emitted items for a given period of time. However it will also emit an empty array when no items emits from the source, you can use `filter` to omit the empty array though.

Here's an example:

```
// assume a web socket stream
ws$;

const notEmpty = arr => Boolean(arr.length);

const grouped$ = ws$.pipe(bufferTime(1000), filter(notEmpty));

grouped$.subscribe(group => {
// group is an array of item from ws$
// do something here
});
```